# Datetimepicker is not highlighting day on hover

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I'm using the datetimepicker of bootstrap, but the thing is that is not highlighting the day on which the mouse is hover. this is the code that I have in the html:

```
    <div class="form-group">                                  
        <div class='input-group date' data-date-startdate="12/12/2012 20:00" name="datepicker" data-date-for
mat="YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" id='datetimepicker1' >
                                                                <input type='text' class="form-control" id="fecha" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss">
       <span class="input-group-addon">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
         </span>
       </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

in the JS I have:

```
$('.input-group.date').each(function() {
            $(this).datetimepicker().on('dp.hide',function (ev) {

                if(confirm('are you sure you want to change?')){
                    //something
                    }).error(function(result) {
                        alert('error');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

This is working pretty well, but the thing is that it's not highlighting the day that I'm hovering

**EDIT:**
I'm importing this:

```
<script src="{{ asset('adminlte/plugins/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your Javascript isn't valid -- I think you may have copy/pasted it wrong. There are 12 opening parentheses and 13 closing parentheses.

Comment: @Cassie yes, I pasted it wrong